# unpickled object causes segfault when called; whose fault?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, pickle

I am creating a interpolation object with the "tri" module of matplotlib, and would like to pickle it, for in the actual application it takes a long time to generate. Unfortunately, when I call the unpickled object, Python 2.7 crashes with a segfault.

I would like to know three things: 1) How to pickle this LinearTriInterpolator object successfully? 2) Is the segfault due to my ignorance, a problem in matplotlib, or in Pickle? 3) what is causing this?

I have have created a simple test code; when called the first interpolation returns 1.0, and the second, using with a the unpickled object, causes a segfault. cPickle shows the same behavior.

```
from pylab import *
from numpy import *
import cPickle as pickle
import matplotlib.tri as tri

#make points
x=array([0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0])
y=array([0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0])
z=x+y

#make triangulation
triPnts=tri.Triangulation(x,y)
theInterper=tri.LinearTriInterpolator(triPnts,z)

#test interpolator
print 'Iterped value is ',theInterper([0.5],[0.5])

#now pickle and unpickle interper
pickle.dump(theInterper,open('testPickle.pckl','wb'),-1)

#load pickle
unpickled_Interper=pickle.load(open('testPickle.pckl','rb'))

#and test
print 'Iterped value is ',unpickled_Interper([0.5],[0.5])
```

My python is:

> Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.6 | 64-bit | (default, Sep 15 2014,
>   17:43:19)  [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin

Comment: I get `UnpickleableError: Cannot pickle <type 'TrapezoidMapTriFinder'> objects`, which may help you debug...

Comment: Ed -- I get that error when I use the 0 protocol for pickle, again for both cPickle and Pickle... what version of python are you using?